# How many swaps are required for selection sort with a sorted array?

Tags: java

My problem is that the selectionsort shows wrong number of swaps. 
It always shows 0 or some large number. 
When the array given is sorted, it always show a large number or all other unsorted tests are always 0.

```
//this class is called selectionSort. It sorts a given array. 
public class SelectionSort implements ISorter {
    private int swaps;

    public SelectionSort() {}

    @Override
    public ISortStats sort(int[] a) {
        long time = System.nanoTime();
        int swapping = 0;
        int numOfComparisons = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            int min = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
                numOfComparisons++;
                if (a[min] >= a[j]) {
                    min = j;
                }
            }
            swapping = swap(a, i, min, this.swaps);
        }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        SortStats ss = new SortStats("Selection Sort", 
                                     a.length, 
                                     numOfComparisons, 
                                     swapping, 
                                     (endTime - time));
        return ss;
    }

    private int swap(int[] a, int i, int j, int swapping) {
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
        return swapping++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This indentation is ... insane.

Comment: Not anymore :) .

Comment: not totally sure, but this looks suspicious to me: `swapping = swap(a, i, min, this.swaps);`. Maybe you meant `swapping = swap(a, i, min, swapping);`?

Comment: @Turing85 it is this.swaps = swap(a, i, min, swapping);

Comment: @Dukeling it is pass by value.

Comment: This would've been a good opportunity to learn how to debug. That should fairly quickly show you that you're using 2 variables to represent swaps and you keep using the one to overwrite the other's value.

Comment: What's the idea behind using 2 variables for that anyway? Also, if you have a class variable, you might as well use that and directly increase it in `swap`, no need to pass it in and return the increased value (although "good" coding practice would probably be to have your sort method be static and not do this).

Comment: swaps was not working, so i planned on using swapping, the second variable. I was using swaps before, but then i changed it to this way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have swaps as a class member, but this line is definitely wrong

```
swapping = swap(a, i, min, this.swaps);
```

As you are never updating this.swaps

Comment: How can i change it? @ControlAltDel

Comment: just remove it and use `swapping`

Comment: @TeslaCarsForLife by changing your code. We cannot tell you how you should write your code. At the moment, you pass in the value of `this.swaps` (which, if uninitialized and unchanged, will always be `0`) to `swap(...)`.

Comment: I changed the code to this.swaps = swap(a, i, min, swapping); but i am still getting 0.

Comment: @TeslaCarsForLife make a pen&paper test. Your "fix" introduces another problem, especially because you print `swapping` instead of `this.swap` (this is not the only problem though...)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SelectionSort implements ISorter {
      private int swaps;
      public SelectionSort(){
      }

      @Override
      public ISortStats sort(int[] a) {
            long time = System.nanoTime();
            int swapping =0;
            int numOfComparisons = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
                  int min = i;      

                  for (int j=i+1; j < a.length; j++) {
                        numOfComparisons++;
                        if (a[min] >= a[j]) {
                              min = j;  

                        }

                  }

                  swapping = swap(a, i, min, swapping);

            }

            long endTime = System.nanoTime();
            SortStats ss = new SortStats("Selection Sort", a.length, numOfComparisons, swapping, (endTime -time));
            return ss ;
      }           

      private static int swap (int[] a, int i, int j, int swapping){
            if(!(order(a))){
                  swapping++;
                  int temp = a[i];
                  a[i] = a[j];
                  a[j] = temp;
            }
            return swapping;
      }
      private static boolean order(int[] arr){
            int count = 0; 
            //this loop runs thru the array to check if it is in order.
            for(int a = 0; a < arr.length-1; a++){
                  if(arr[a] <= arr[a+1]){ // if true count plus 1
                        count++; 
                  }
            }
            if(count == arr.length-1){ // checks if the count and arr length -1 is equal 
                  return true; // if equal it will return true
            }
            return false; // returns false if the array is not correctly sorted.
      }


}
```